# Which Layout is better to use?

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-emulator

In My Application i have to use the Calculator.
The Different Button in Calculator should be like below image.
[image]

So, What should be better to implement such type of the Layout ?
I think gridView is good, but while thinking about the "0" Button and the Button below "C" button, I dont know how to set it in to the gridview.
So Anybudy tell me which one is the Best way to set this type of layout ?
recently i have use the relative layout to set this layout.
Please help me regarding this. and if the GridView is nice with this then tell me what should i have to do with that two buttons: one is "0" button and second is the Button that is below thee Button of "left errow".

Code to have Use the RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/calculationButtonLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/totalAmount" android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/linear_layout" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <!-- First row Start -->

                <Button android:id="@+id/sevenNumber" 
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="7" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/eightNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sevenNumber"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="8" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/nineNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eightNumber"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="9" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>    

                <Button android:id="@+id/acButton" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nineNumber"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="AC" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/brown_button"/>

            <!-- First row Finish -->

            <!-- Second row Start -->

                <Button android:id="@+id/fourNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/sevenNumber" 
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="4" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/fiveNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/eightNumber"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="5" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/sixNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fiveNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/nineNumber"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="6" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>    

                <Button android:id="@+id/clearButton" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sixNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/acButton"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="C" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/brown_button"/>

            <!-- Second row finish -->

            <!-- Third row Start -->


                <Button android:id="@+id/oneNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/fourNumber" 
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="1" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/twoNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/oneNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/fiveNumber"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="2" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/threeNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twoNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/sixNumber"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="3" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>    



            <!-- Third row finish -->

            <!-- Fourth row Start -->


                <Button android:id="@+id/zeroNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/oneNumber"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:text="0" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/dotNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zeroNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/threeNumber"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="." android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/doNothing" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/threeNumber" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/do_nothing_button" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dotNumber" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/threeNumber"/>

            <!-- Third row finish -->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The Image that i  got after this Layout is:
[image]

In this Image the Keypad is not fit to the Whole Middle Window. I want to fit it in to the Window also.
So What should i have to do for it ?

Comment: you should have paste the code here as you have already mentioned in your question "recently i have use the relative layout to set this layout."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Relative layout` as it will adjust itself with different resolution screens.

Comment: Every Layout adjust itself accordingly except Absolute which is deprecated now but the also I like like your answer so +1

Comment: @ingsaurabh: It's true. I find relative easy to use as per different screens.

Comment: @Vinnet Shukla: Thanks for the Reply. I have use Relative Layout for it. But its not appearing well as i want.

Comment: @Vineet: Please See My Edited Question. I have Use the RelativeLayout But While i am Running it in to the Device, its not seem Well as i want. I mean "1","2" and "3" number is get behind the Layout available After this whole relativelayout.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. And Also Check the Edited Question Again. I have Puted the Screen shot what i get after implement this code.

Comment: @Vineet: I will wait for your reply so please dont forget it.

Comment: add android:layout_centerVertical="true", in your RelativeLayout where android:id="@+id/calculationButtonLayout"..

Comment: @Vineet: I have Done it But still the Problem is same.

Answer (score 1):

Use Relative layout because its have more functionality and also easier than other layout ................... and you have also set component toRightof and toLeftof and also many functionality////////

Comment: Please See My Edited Question. For it. But While i am Running it in to Screen its not seem well.